# Calculating frost frequency in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to work with frost and several metrics

First, I want to map the number of nights that have temperatures below 0 in a year. This code seems to do this.

Second, I want to calculate the number of days between the first and last night with temperatures below zero.

How can I get the frequency of frost for the month of October since 2002 or better still in a decidical way? Sum of values below 0 ° C divided amount of values without clouds.

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/20e6accd99765fca9fef98371e02c366

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Google Earth Engine developer forum, a similar question was raised with days since the last rainfall. It was called [max number of consecutive dry days](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-engine-developers/XRznPFYyZ08) and it should provide you with a basis on which to conduct your own analyses.

Two different solutions were proposed. Guide Lemoine had a [solution](https://code.earthengine.google.com/13d478458daab7fd20e6c144cf77950c) that created a raster with total days and length since last dry day. Jamon Van Den Hoek had [another solution](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3e41a1ef185ffc2ededd46bc68f7e86?noload=true) with slightly different outputs.

Comment: Very good!, THANK.
"Probability of temperature less 0 degree"
I am work with the script